# middleware (Roles de usuario) en laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy en el desarrollo de un sistema de recursos humanos, para lo cual estoy usando laravel en su versión 5.2.
pero estoy en un dilema al usar **middleware**, hasta el momento tengo 3 tipos de roles, el **Administrador**, **Adminstrativo** y por ultimo el **Docente** que estos son mis roles de usuario.

**Kernel.php**

```
 protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'super' => \App\Http\Middleware\Super::class,
    'docentes' => \App\Http\Middleware\docentes::class,
    'administrativo' => \App\Http\Middleware\Administrativo::class,
];
```

Aqui muestro mis middlewares creados

**Authenticate.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Authenticate
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
        //verificamos que tipo de usuario es si es docente mande al login de docente
        if ($guard == 'docente'){
            return redirect()->guest('docente/login');
        }
        return redirect()->guest('login');

        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Nota** Aqui manejo dos tipos de login

**Administrativo.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Administrativo
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (Auth::User()->tipo == 2) {
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return abort(403);
        }
    }
}
```

No pongo los demas middlewares debido a que tienen la misma estructura solo cambia en la parte de `tipo`.

Mi problema reside al crear los route groups y asignarles url, cuando la url se repite en otro routegroup pero de distinto middleware me marca el error 403.

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','super']], function () {
    Route::get('modules/personal/','PersonalController@inicio');
}

Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','administrativo']], function (){
    Route::get('modules/personal/','PersonalController@inicio');
});
```

Cuando hago esto y entro como adminstrativo me funciona la ruta, pero cuando entro como super usuario me manda el acceso denegado.

**¿Entonces como seria la forma correcta de agregar permisos en el sistema usando middleware?**

soy un poco nuevo en laravel gracias por su atención.

Comment: Si usas 2 roles para entrar a una misma ruta, no te convendría definir un un solo middle?. Es bastante rebuscado me parece lo que queres hacer, por lo general se usan para restringir caminos (en su forma simple). En ese caso por ahi podes limitar el acceso por codigo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si utilizaras Laravel 5.3 podrías autorizar acciones usando Policies en el middleware:

```
use App\Post;

Route::put('/post/{post}', function (Post $post) {
    // The current user may update the post...
})->middleware('can:update,post');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#via-middleware

---

Desconozco si esto es posible hacerlo en 5.2, en caso que no sea posible, lo mejor siempre será seguir las opciones de autorización que ofrece Laravel, definiendo habilidades, y si tu aplicación lo amerita, Policies, lo cual puede ser un poco complejo al comienzo, pero te permitirá tener una mejor separación de tu lógica.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authorization

---

Si definitivamente quieres hacer verificación de acceso a las rutas por medio del middleware, yo haría la verificación de los permisos en un solo middleware, pues lo que estás haciendo actualmente es definir la ruta dos veces y estás llamando a ambos middleware, además de hacer más dificil el mantenimiento de las rutas, las cuales deberían estar definidas solo una vez.

Tus roles y sus prioridades o jerarquía deberían estar definidos antes de utilizar el middleware, con lo cual estarías realizando un esquema similar al de las habilidades y Policies explicado arriba, pero con un acercamiento mucho más pobre, menos entendible y más dificil de mantener.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario estaba esperandoa que tu comentaras, no hay una forma de definir roles entonces en laravel 5.2? ya que pues es proyecto esta demaciado avanzado para migrar al 5.3, no sabras de alguna libreria extra para tener este tipo de roles de usuario?

Comment: Por defecto no hay algo así en Laravel 5.2, sin embargo puedes jugar un poco y crear algo sencillo con algo de autorizaciones, como lo que está en este enlace: http://laravel-tricks.com/tricks/simple-user-role-laravel-52 . La creación y administración de varios roles generalmente la hago con las policies y los modelos, y los aplico en middlewares o donde los necesite sin generar redundancia. Podrías revisar también JWT o Entrust.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo estas solo estas validando un solo tipo de perfil ==2 es decir que los demas no podran acceder también puedes bloquear los controladores desde los public function __construct()
{ 
  $this->middleware('administrativo');
}

Comment: Hola! gracias por tu comentario, si te fijas ahi tambien dejo en claro que no pongos los demas middleware, ya que solo cambia la estructura de tipo de perfil, si tengo los demas middleware :)